# Converting a few rules from .htacess to NGINX

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

I am trying to get a few `.htaccess` rules converted to NGINX, but it's not going very well. I have to crawl here and beg for assistance :(~ Paypal-beer to anyone who solves it.

I have tried some online converters, but the code looks messy, and I don't quite understand what it's doing. The rules I would like to have converted:

```
# Rewrite any calls to html|json|xml|atom|rss
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss)$ $1/ [L]

# Rewrite any calls to /render to the image resizer
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} render/
RewriteRule ^render/. app/parsers/slir/ [L]

# Rewrite routes to application index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?/$1/ [L,QSA]
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is sorted. Inside a NGINX `server {}` block, I included the following:

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){

    # Rewrite any calls to html|json|xml|atom|rss if a folder matching * exists
    rewrite (.+)\.(html|json|xml|atom|rss)$ $1/ last;

    # Rewrite any calls to /render to the X3 image resizer
    rewrite ^/render/. /app/parsers/slir/ last;

    # Rewrite routes to X3 application index.php if they are non-existent files/dirs
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 last;
  }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/mjau-mjau/6dc1948284c90d167f51f1e566a8457b